# rules to import csv data as a list or as a dictionary for text analysis?

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, dictionary

I scrapped some product reviews and stored the data in CSV with below format. I want to import this csv file to Python to process text analysis, specifically column **Review Details** and **Recommendation**.

Is it better to import the data as a list with csv.reader()? or as a dictionary with csv.DictReader()? I will add few columns into the table, such as tokens, etc.

This is prolly a very basic question, but I am new to Python as well as NLTK. I have watched some MOOC courses and NLTK books, but there's simply no emphasis on this at all. Thank you for your help!

```
Author', 'Rating', 'Review Title', '**Review Details**', '**Recommandetion**'

A      , 5       ,  Great!       , knsdfiuygbblvbs , recommend to a friend 

B      , 1       ,  Bad!         , knsdfiuygbblvbs , not recommend 

C      , 3       ,  So-So!       , knsdfiuygbblvbs , recommend to a friend 

D      , 2       ,  Meh!         , knsdfiuygbblvbs , not recommend
```